# How to write a `<<` operator for boost::tuple?

Tags: c++, ostringstream, boost-tuples

In the sample code below, it shows that boost::tuple can be created implicitly from the first template argument. 
Because of that I am not able to write a `<<` operator as it becomes ambiguous.

Also I don't understand why `ostringstream& << float` is also ambiguous. This does not have any implicit construction. Why does this also give ambiguous error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Myclass
{
};

typedef boost::tuple<int,float,Myclass> Mytuple;

ostringstream& operator<<(ostringstream& os_, Mytuple tuple_)
{
  float f = tuple_.get<1>();
  //os_ << (int)tuple_.get<0>(); // Error because int is implicitly converted into Mytuple. WHYY?
  //os_ << tuple_.get<1>();      // No Clue Why this is ambiguous.
  //os_ << tuple_.get<2>();      // Error because no matching operator. Fine.
  return os_;
}

int main()
{
  Mytuple t1;
  t1 = 3;      // Working because int is implicitly converted into Mytuple!! WHY?
  //t1 = 3.0f; // Error because no matching constructor. Fine.
  return 0;
}
```

Error Mesasge:

> tupleTest2.C:18: error: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even
>   though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst
>   conversion for the second:

Comment: `boost::tuple` already has an `operator<<` much like that.  I don't see how that leads to the errors you're getting but it may be related.

Comment: Also `boost::tuple` has constructors for 0..n of the tuple elements, so yours has a constructor `Mytuple(int)` which makes it convertible from `int`.

Comment: It compiles fine for me -as it should- with gcc 4.5 and gcc 4.7 experimental. What compiler version are you using?

Comment: I tried commenting my operator function. I get a no matching operator error when I do `stream << tuple1`.

Comment: @rodrigo did you try uncommenting any of the lines? It fails when I try to uncomment this line `os_ << tuple_.get<1>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with the tuple, but with your operator. This works fine :

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os_, Mytuple tuple_)
{
    os_ << tuple_.get<0>(); // Error because int is implicitly converted into Mytuple. WHYY?
    os_ << tuple_.get<1>();      // No Clue Why this is ambiguous.
    //os_ << tuple_.get<2>();      // Error because no matching operator. Fine.
    return os_;
}
```

The problem is that the ostringstream inherit `operator<<` from ostream, which has this signature :  `ostringstream& operator<<(ostringstream& os_, Mytuple tuple_)` is allowed. Then the

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, T t)
```

(change T with all available types in c++, see [operator<< reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)

**EDIT**

Here is a simplified example (without a tuple) :

```
ostringstream& operator<<(ostringstream& os_, Mytuple tuple_)
{
    const int i = tuple_.get<0>();
    os_ << i; // error in this line
    return os_;
}
```

and the error is now :

```
dfg.cpp: In function ‘std::ostringstream& operator<<(std::ostringstream&, Mytuple)’:
dfg.cpp:18: error: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.3.0/../../../../include/c++/4.3.0/bits/ostream.tcc:111: note: candidate 1: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
dfg.cpp:14: note: candidate 2: std::ostringstream& operator<<(std::ostringstream&, Mytuple)
```

The above error message says : it is not possible to choose between two operators `operator<<(ostream&,...)` and `operator<<(ostringstream&,...). This also raises another question : why on earth do you need`operator<<(ostringstream&,...)`?

Comment: Can you explain what the problem was?

Comment: It works. But why does this work but `ostringstream` does not work? Actually I want this to work with my custom stream.

Comment: I don't understand. Yes, ostream has operator<< for primitive types. Why should that be ambiguous with a custom operator which takes a custom class?

Comment: Additional explanation added. If you still don't understand please write, and I'll extend the answer

Comment: @VJo Thanks. Its clear now. Actually the stream I am using is not ostringstream/ostream but a custom stream which is internally used by a custom persistant map to write the object to disk. I replaced the tuple with a simple struct and got things working for now.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
 os << tuple_.get<0>();
```

there is no function that matches both parameters. Instead the compiler has a choice to apply an implicit conversion on either parameter

```
std::ostream << int
```

or

```
std::ostringstream << MyTuple
```

The latter would happen with the `boost::tuple` constructor that can take any number of arguments up to number of tuple elements. (And with `float` it fails, because `float` is convertible to `int`.)

When overloading stream operators, use the base class as the left hand side (`ostream` or even `basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>`.

---

**Edit:** You could disambiguate the call by casting the **first** argument.

```
ostringstream& operator<<(ostringstream& os_, Mytuple tuple_)
{
  static_cast<std::ostream&>(os_) << tuple_.get<0>(); 
  static_cast<std::ostream&>(os_)  << tuple_.get<1>();      
  static_cast<std::ostream&>(os_)  << tuple_.get<2>();      // Error because no matching operator. Fine.
  return os_;
}
```

However, overloading the operator with `ostringstream` is still a bad idea, because it won't work with operator chaining.

```
MyTuple a, b;
ostringstream ss;
ss << a << ' ' << b;
```

will invoke:

1) `ostringstream& operator<<(ostringstream& os_, Mytuple tuple_)`

2) `ostream& ostream::operator<<(char)`

3) **`ostream& operator<<(ostream&&, boost::tuple<int,float,Myclass>`**

Comment: It would be easier to disambiguate writing: `os.operator<<(tuple_.get<1>());`

Answer (score 1):

All those people telling you to use `::std::ostream` for the type instead of `::std::ostringstream` are absolutely correct. You shouldn't be using `::std::ostringstream` that way.

But my main beef with your code is the distressing lack of generality. It only works for one particular tuple type, and not all of them.

So I wrote an `operator <<` for `::std::tuple` in C++0x that works for any tuple who's members can be individually written using `operator <<`. It can probably be translated relatively easily to work with Boost's tuple type. Here it is:

```
template < ::std::size_t fnum, typename tup_type>
void print_fields(::std::ostream &os, const tup_type &val)
{
   if (fnum < ::std::tuple_size<tup_type>::value) {
      ::std::cerr << "Fred " << fnum << '\n';
      os << ::std::get<fnum, tup_type>(val);
      if (::std::tuple_size<tup_type>::value > (fnum + 1)) {
         os << ", ";
      }
      print_fields<fnum + 1, tup_type>(os, val);
   }
}

template < ::std::size_t fnum, typename... Elements>
class field_printer;

template <typename... Elements>
class field_printer<0, Elements...> {
 public:
   typedef ::std::tuple<Elements...> tup_type;

   static void print_field(::std::ostream &os, const tup_type &val) {
   }
};

template < ::std::size_t fnum, typename... Elements>
class field_printer {
 public:
   typedef ::std::tuple<Elements...> tup_type;

   static void print_field(::std::ostream &os, const tup_type &val) {
      constexpr auto tupsize = ::std::tuple_size<tup_type>::value;
      os << ::std::get<tupsize - fnum, Elements...>(val);
      if (fnum > 1) {
         os << ", ";
      }
      field_printer<fnum - 1, Elements...>::print_field(os, val);
   }
};

template <class... Types>
::std::ostream &operator <<(::std::ostream &os, const ::std::tuple<Types...> &val)
{
   typedef ::std::tuple<Types...> tup_type;
   os << '(';
   field_printer< ::std::tuple_size<tup_type>::value, Types...>::print_field(os, val);
   return os << ')';
}
```

This prints out the tuple as `"(element1, element2, ...elementx)"`.